# Nonlinear fit where expression has uncertain numbers

Tags: fitting, error-propagation

I am trying to fit my data (which has error) to an expression of the form $y = \frac{a}{(bx+c)^2}$, where b and c are the parameters I wish to estimate. a is a known number with an uncertainty : $a = 5\pm0.003$. I don't know how to input this value of a in the expression. Using Around[5,0.003] does not execute the fit.

Here is the code :

```
In[130]:= values = {10, 21, 54, 68, 97, 99, 101, 102}; 

In[131]:= points = {3, 5, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21}; 

In[132]:= 
data = Table[{points[[i]], values[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[points]}]; 

In[133]:= error = {0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.15}; 

In[134]:= a = Around[5, 0.003]; 

In[135]:= exp = a/(b*x + c)^2; 

In[136]:= nlm = 
 NonlinearModelFit[data, exp, {b, c}, {x}, Weights -> 1/error^2, 
  VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 & )]

Out[136]= NonlinearModelFit[{{3, 10}, {5, 21}, {13, 54}, {17, 
   68}, {18, 97}, {19, 99}, {20, 101}, {21, 102}}, 
   Around[5., 0.003]/(c + b*x)^2, {b, c}, {x}, 
 Weights -> {99.99999999999999, 24.999999999999996, 
       99.99999999999999, 44.44444444444444, 24.999999999999996, 
   11.11111111111111, 99.99999999999999, 
       44.44444444444444}, VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 & )]
```

Comment: Hi @aphy11, welcome to Mathematica SE. So you get an idea about how the site works, please start by taking the [tour] (follow the link). The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): 
A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). Please share your code attempts and tell us how you expect the answer you are looking for is different from doing the fit without considering uncertainty.

Comment: Added the code. The code executes when I enter say a=5. But I want to include the uncertainty in a.

Comment: If the parameter `a` already has a value with uncertainty (or prior) then what is the precise mathematical problem that you expect `NonlinearModelFit` to solve for you? Just saying that one parameter has a value and uncertainty does not mean there is well-defined problem. Secondary remark: The model `exp` is redundant in the sense that replacing $(a,b,c)$ by $(\lambda^2 a,\lambda b,\lambda c)$ for any $\lambda \neq 0$ yields the same model.

Comment: I just want my fit to take into account the error in one of the numbers (a) in my fit expression -- want to see how the error propagates in the estimates for b and c. I am no mathematica expert, so I am not even sure if the NonlinearModelFit is the right thing to use. If (a) has a fixed value then the problem is not redundant.

Comment: Here is an attempt: Let me denote by $b(a)$ and $c(a)$ the best fit values for a given $a$. In the case $a=5$ the `NonlinearModelFit` gives $b(5) = 0.0142548$ and $c(5) = -0.509528$. On the other hand from the $\lambda$-symmetry in my previous comment, $b(a)$ is equal to a constant times $\sqrt{a}$ and same for $c(a)$. This gives `b[a_] := 0.00637494*Sqrt[a]` and `c[a_] := -0.227868*Sqrt[a]`. Then you can calculate the error propagation using `b[Around[5,0.003]]` and `c[Around[5,0.003]]`. Is this what you want?

Comment: While this works for the toy model using the redundancy you pointed to, I would like to know how to do this for more general cases. I am particularly interested in $y = p - \frac{a}{x -b - c/x^2}$, where p,b, and c are the parameters I wish to estimate. (a) is the known number with some uncertainty. I want the error in (a) to be taken into account when doing the fit -- what I am interested in is the chi squared, the fit residuals, and the std. errors in the fit parameters.

Comment: @aphy11.  Then you need to ask a different question about that very different situation where the redundancy in the model doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `NMinimize` to this end as follows (pay your attention to the constraints `a >= 4.997 && a <= 5.003`).

```
points = {3, 5, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21};
values = {10, 21, 54, 68, 97, 99, 101, 102};
weights = {99.99999999999999, 24.999999999999996, 99.99999999999999, 
44.44444444444444, 24.999999999999996, 11.11111111111111, 
99.99999999999999, 44.44444444444444};
NMinimize[{Sum[weights[[j]]/(Sum[weights[[k]], {k, 1, 8}])*(a/(b*points[[j]] + c)^2 - 
values[[j]])^2, {j, 1, 8}], }, {a, b, c}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> `84.1657, {a -> 5.0024, b -> -0.0142582, c -> 0.50965}}`

Other methods produce the same result up to signs. Now we visualize the obtained result by

```
p1 = ListPlot[Table[{points[[n]], values[[n]]}, {n, 1, 8}]];
p2 = plot[a/(b*x + c)^2 /. {a -> 5.001226813606488`, 
b -> 0.014256528874175027`, c -> -0.5095904009681361`}, {x, 0, 21}];
Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Addition. In your notations and

```
ex[a_] := a/(b*x + c)^2
f[a_] := NonlinearModelFit[data, ex[a], {b, c}, {x}, Weights -> 1/error^2, 
VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 &)]
f[4.999]
```

> FittedModel[4.999/(-<<19>>+<<21>> x)^2]

```
%["ParameterTable"]
```

> $$\begin{array}{l|llll}
>  \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
> \hline
>  b & 0.0142534 & 0.0000326885 & 436.036 & \text{9.820536554820526$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-15} \\
>  c & -0.509477 & 0.000640458 & -795.489 & \text{2.6637195427445536$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-16} \\
> \end{array} $$
> and so on.

Answer (score 1):

***Apologies:***  I didn't read @user293787 's comment carefully enough.  The answer below is essentially what was suggested in that comment.

Your model (ignoring the weights) is the following:

$$y=a/(b x+c)^2 + \text{error}$$

But as pointed out by @user293787 your model of overparameterized if $a$ is not known.  There are essentially just two parameters that can be estimated from the data:

$$y=1/\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}} x+\frac{c}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2 + \text{error}$$

So we fit the model

$$y=1/(b_0 x+c_0)^2 + \text{error}$$

```
values = {10, 21, 54, 68, 97, 99, 101, 102};
points = {3, 5, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21};
data = Transpose[{values, points}];

model = 1/(b0 x + c0)^2
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {b0, c0}, x]
pte = nlm["ParameterTableEntries"]
```

Now we can use `Around` to get an estimate of the uncertainty of $b$ and $c$:

```
b0 = Around[pte[[1, 1]], pte[[1, 2]]];
c0 = Around[pte[[2, 1]], pte[[2, 2]]];
a = Around[5, 0.003];

b = b0 Sqrt[a]
(* Around[0.004052157221886178, 0.001046094100871795] *)
c = c0 Sqrt[a]
(* Around[-0.9045998666312475, 0.10065898813650241`] *)
```

I haven't posted figures showing the fit because I assume that the data and weights are just a made-up example.